# Force a block towards the left

Tags: css

In fact, I would like to put my elements towards the left as below:

[image]

On my `second_text` class, I added `text-align: left;` but I always have the same problem.

```
.second_text{
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

It is possible to force the block to left?

```css
body{
    padding-top:200px;  
}

.container{
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.row{
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-bottom:50px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 10%;

}

.img-block{
  width: 4%;
}

.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-left: 15px;

}

.title{
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.vertical{
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  height: 60px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.img-block {
  height: 28px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.img-pic{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
}


.second_text{
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>HTML CSS JS</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      
      <div class="row">
        
        
      <img class="img-block" src="https://zupimages.net/up/20/21/mz4v.png"  alt="image"/>
      <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="title">Phone</div>
          <div class="second_text">Just For VIP Member</div>
      </div> 
      <div class="vertical"></div>  
        
      <img class="img-block" src="https://zupimages.net/up/20/21/wgl0.png"  alt="image"/>
      <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="title">Email Us</div>
          <div class="second_text">admin@superbtc.biz</div>
      </div>
      <div class="vertical"></div>   
        
      <img class="img-block" src="https://zupimages.net/up/20/34/epbs.png"  alt="image"/>
      <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="title">Follow us</div>
          <div class="second_text">
            <img class="img-pic" src="https://zupimages.net/up/20/34/pnpm.png"  alt="image"/>
            <img class="img-pic" src="https://zupimages.net/up/20/34/qgz1.png"  alt="image"/>
            <img class="img-pic" src="https://zupimages.net/up/20/34/gdph.png"  alt="image"/>
            <img class="img-pic" src="https://zupimages.net/up/20/34/alck.png"  alt="image"/>
            <img class="img-pic" src="https://zupimages.net/up/20/34/evtq.png"  alt="image"/>
        </div>         
      </div>
      <div class="vertical"></div>  
         
      <img class="img-block" src="https://zupimages.net/up/20/34/txjb.png"  alt="image"/>
      <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="title">Address</div>
          <div class="second_text">2699 BORAMBOLA, New South Wales,Australia.</div>
      </div>
   
     </div>
       
      </div>
         

      
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simplified version. Restructure like this

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.row .wrapper {
  flex-grow: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.row .wrapper .first-text {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}

.row .wrapper .second-text {
  padding: 5px 15px;
}

.row .wrapper .first-text img {
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.verticle {
  background: black;
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="first-text">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/30" /> Some text here
    </div>
    <div class="second-text">
      Some text
    </div>
    <div class="verticle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="first-text">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/30" /> Some text here
    </div>
    <div class="second-text">
      Some text
    </div>
    <div class="verticle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="first-text">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/30" /> Some text here
    </div>
    <div class="second-text">
      Some text
    </div>
    <div class="verticle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="first-text">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/30" /> Some text here
    </div>
    <div class="second-text">
      Some text
    </div>
    <div class="verticle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Aravind for your help.

Comment: No worries mate

Answer (score 2):

Try using Negative Values to `.second_text`  i.e Margin-left: -40px
Though this is not a best fix but can be a quick fix.

Comment: Thank you, it's ok now.

Answer (score 1):

A better solution would be to use `position: relative` and `left: -40px` on your `.second_text`.